# Validate an expired ActiveDirectory password using PowerShell or LDAP

Tags: node.js, powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.1

As title said, I need a way to validate an expired password against ActiveDirectory.
It has to be LDAP, or PowerShell, because the user will perform validation via a NodeJS service from another machine running Linux.

I have tried using System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry like this below, but it can't validate an expired one. I want the user to replace their own expired password, but not before it is validated.

```
async testPassword(user, password) {
    const testCommand = `(New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry '', '${ user }' , '${ password }')`;
    try {
        const result = await this.exec(testCommand);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

Most of the solution involved a dll library, which is not available in Linux, the second solution I found involves re-enabling the password before validating, which is not ideal. The other questions simply has no answers.
I don't mind an error message or anything, as long as I can distinguish between wrong password and correct and expired password. And it has to work in linux ecosystem.

Comment: *"I want the user to replace their own expired password, but not before it is validated."* - Is there a reason you're doing it in two steps (validating, then changing)? When a user changes their password, they have to provide the old, correct password anyway. It can all be done in one step.

Comment: Well, there is a command to replace the password without validating. And it is working, by using administrator password. But I don't see anything to validate expired user's password. I would like it if it can be done in one step though. Either way, I need user to log into the browser app before continuing into company's application, and replace the password if it is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a node.js package to do all of this, rather than calling out to PowerShell to use a .NET class. For example, you can do the job with the [activedirectory2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) package.

There is an example of how authenticate in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049476/1202807). You'll notice that the error message in that answer has `data 52e`. That is the reason for the failure. The `52e` is the hex value of the Windows System Error Code, which can be looked up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-#:%7E:text=of%20the%20domain.-,ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE,-1326%20(0x52E)). All the reasons for failure are listed there too. For example, `532` would mean ["The password for this account has expired."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-#:%7E:text=The%20password%20for%20this%20account%20has%20expired.)

For some reason, `DirectoryEntry` doesn't give you that information.

Then, if you want to change the user's password (using the old, correct password), you can use the code in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/issues/127#issuecomment-205286604), which I'll paste below too. You must be connected via an encrypted method to change or reset the password, such as LDAPS.

```
 /**
 * Change user password
 *
 * WARN : this function needs to an LDAPS connection to works. 
 *
 * @public
 * @param {String} username The username to retrieve the user.
 * @param {String} oldPassword The oldPassword to authenticate user.
 * @param {String} newPassword The new password to change user's password.
 * @param {Function} callback The callback to execute when the changePassword is completed. callback(err: {Object}, result: {Object})
 */
ActiveDirectory.prototype.changePassword = function changePassword(username, oldPassword, newPassword, callback) {
  /**
   * Inline function to encode string to base 64
   *
   * @private
   */
  function encodePassword(password) {
    return new Buffer('"' + password + '"', 'utf16le').toString();
  }

  var client = createClient.call(this);

  client.search(this.baseDN, {
    filter: '(cn=' + username + ')',
    attributes: 'dn',
    scope: 'sub'
  }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return;
    }
    res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
      var userDN = entry.object.dn;
      client.bind(userDN, oldPassword, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
          return;
        }
        client.modify(userDN, [
          new ldap.Change({
            operation: 'delete',
            modification: {
              unicodePwd: encodePassword(oldPassword)
            }
          }),
          new ldap.Change({
            operation: 'add',
            modification: {
              unicodePwd: encodePassword(newPassword)
            }
          })
        ], function(err) {
          if (err) {
            callback(err);
          } else {
            callback();
            client.unbind();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```